# Compare two nested object lists based on the List<string> values in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have three lists, two object lists to be compared based on the third list which is of type string and the resultant should be the common values from both the lists.
Example

```
 List<Object1>

 - Name
 - ID
 -  AddressList[]

       AddressList Item
         - State
         - City
         - Zip
      AddressList Item
         - State
         - City
         - Zip

List<Object1>

 - Name
 - ID
 -  AddressList[]

       AddressList Item
         - State
         - City
         - Zip

       AddressList Item
         - State
         - City
         - Zip


List<string> = new List<string> {"State","City"};
```

In this case only the values of State and City must be compared. If the List= new List {"State"} then only the State values from both the list objects needs to be compared.

I've been trying to find a way to do this by myself but I feel like everything I did is completely wrong. I'd be more than happy if someone could help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I feel you are abusing List but maybe not. What do you mean by compare? What is the input and expected output? Please create a *working* [mcve] (emphasis on working) that demonstrates your problem. (By working I mean something that compiles and can run, it does not have to produce the expected result)

Comment: Typically a comparer should be used for this kind of comparison. But to do that you need to know which properties to compare. Perhaps you can write two comparers and use them based on the values of your 3rd list.

Comment: Having sample data and expected output would help.  If I understood the question correctly, then maybe you are looking for a LINQ Zip (if the position of the Object1s are significant) between the first two lists, and changing the third list to a lamda expression for the actual comparison after being zipped.  If you want to compare properties of Object1's based on ID, then that requires a different solution (probably join and compare or possibly intersect).

Comment: Can you provide an example with each of the lists and exactly what is being compared?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not at all clear what you are trying to do. What is the "example?" When you say that you want to compare two lists, it's not clear what you mean. When you say that you want to compare two lists based on a third list, it's even less clear.

Comment: Thank you all. As Igor mentioned, i am making it more complex on the c# side.  I am going to handle it in database using joins which can give me common elements of lists based on conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There are some open source libraries that provide that kind of functionality, such as ObjectComparer: https://github.com/ValeraT1982/ObjectsComparer

It allows you to compary variable number of properties such as this:

```
//Initialize objects and comparer
var a1 = new ClassA { StringProperty = "String", IntProperty = 1 };
var a2 = new ClassA { StringProperty = "String", IntProperty = 1 };
var comparer = new Comparer<ClassA>();

//Compare objects
IEnumerable<Difference> differences;
var isEqual = comparer.Compare(a1, a2, out differences);

//Print results
Debug.WriteLine(isEqual ? "Objects are equal" : string.Join(Environment.NewLine, differenses));
```

Without using a third party library, you would need to use reflection to compare them dynamically like that.

Something like this(missing all kinds of safety code):

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(Object1).GetProperty(propName);
object valueA;
object valueB;

valueA = propertyInfo.GetValue(objectA, null);
valueB = propertyInfo.GetValue(objectB, null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: No problem happy to help. If it helped you solve your problem, go ahead and accept the answer so others can see it has been solved. Thanks!